# parse api response not completly "json" with retofit and Moshi

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit2, moshi

I found and api, that I wnat to try, but the response is not "full  json" , so when I get the response I get an error of parser.

As usual I'm using retrofit, so more or less the important part is like:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AwsomeAPIConstants.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        awsomeApi = retrofit.create(AwsomeaApiService::class.java)
```

As I said, all the responses of the API are like: `<sentence> = {<json>}` an obviously the MoshiConverter can't parse it.

Some examples of response:

```
info={'timestamp':1292608331,'error':0}

info={'status':1,'error':0}

search={'error':1}
```

Is there any way to parse it?

Comment: `MoshiConverterFactory.create().asLenient()` will work if that's really like {search={'error':1}}. if it's not like JSON at all, you may need to read part of the response body first and then delegate.

Comment: Thanks @EricCochran . I'll take a look. this afternoon and tell you something.

Comment: @EricCochran didn' work, effectively is not a json. How can I parse the body?

Comment: I would have a Retrofit response body converter that takes the body's source, finds the index of the first equals sign, skips through that index, and then delegates to a lenient JSON response body converter.

Answer (score 0):

Make a response body converter that takes the response body's source, skips the leading bytes, and delegates.
Here is an example with an added annotation to mark service methods that have this prefix in their response bodies.

```
final class Foo {
  long timestamp;
  int error;
}

interface FooService {
  @EqualsJson @GET("/") Call<Foo> foo();
}

@Test public void foo() throws IOException {
  MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
  server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("info={'timestamp':1292608331,'error':0}"));
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(server.url("/"))
      .addConverterFactory(new EqualsJson.ResponseBodyConverterFactory())
      .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create().asLenient())
      .build();
  FooService fooService = retrofit.create(FooService.class);

  Call<Foo> call = fooService.foo();
  Response<Foo> response = call.execute();
  Foo body = response.body();
  assertThat(body.timestamp).isEqualTo(1292608331);
  assertThat(body.error).isEqualTo(0);
}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface EqualsJson {
  final class ResponseBodyConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(
        Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
      for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
        Annotation annotation = annotations[i];
        if (annotation instanceof EqualsJson) {
          Annotation[] nextAnnotations = new Annotation[annotations.length - 1];
          System.arraycopy(
              annotations, 0, nextAnnotations, 0, i);
          System.arraycopy(
              annotations, i + 1, nextAnnotations, i, annotations.length - i - 1);
          return new ResponseBodyConverter(
              retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, nextAnnotations));
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    static final class ResponseBodyConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, Object> {
      static final ByteString JSON_PREFIX = ByteString.encodeUtf8("=");

      final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate;

      ResponseBodyConverter(Converter<ResponseBody, Object> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
      }

      @Override
      public Object convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        BufferedSource source = value.source();
        source.skip(source.indexOf(JSON_PREFIX) + 1);
        return delegate.convert(
            ResponseBody.create(value.contentType(), value.contentLength(), source));
      }
    }
  }
}
```